# How to expose a service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

My organization offers Containers as a Service through Rancher. I start a rabbitmq service using some web interface. The service started OK. I'm having trouble accessing this service through an external IP.

Using kubectl, I tried to get the list of the running services:

```
$ kubectl get services -n flash
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE
rabbitmq-ha             ClusterIP   XX.XX.X.XXX   <none>        15672/TCP,5672/TCP,4369/TCP   46m
rabbitmq-ha-discovery   ClusterIP   None          <none>        15672/TCP,5672/TCP,4369/TCP   46m
```

How do I expose the 'rabbitmq-ha' service to the external word so I can access it via *IP address*:15672, etc? Right now, the external IP is none. I'm not sure how to get kubernetes to assign one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in supported cloud environment(AWS, GCP, Azure...etc) then you can create a service of type [Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) and an external Load Balancer will be provisioned and an external IP or DNS will be assigned by your cloud provider.[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) is the docs on this.

If you are on bare metal on prem then you can use [melatLB](https://metallb.universe.tf) which provides an implementation of LoadBalancer.

Apart from above you can also use [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) Type service to expose a service to be accessible outside your kubernetes cluster. Here is [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) on how to do that.

One disadvantage of using LoadBalancer type service is that for every service an external load balancer will be provisioned which is costly, as an alternative you can use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) abstraction. Ingress is implemented by many softwares such as nginx, HAProxy, traefik.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed Rancher portal has the ability to add Ingress to an app. I was able to set it up and I can access the admin interface to RabbitMq from a web browser now.